# Replacing all <em>|</em> tag from html page wtih underscore(_) with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I would like to replace all `<em>` and `</em>` tags on a webpage with _

Markdown likes to turn _ into  tag however the data is being pulled from a text file and has actual underscores that are not being displayed correctly. I have done alot of searching but can't find anything to solve this issue. I have no server side includes available.

```
document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = document.getElementById("list").innerHTML.replace(/<em>|<\/em>/g,"_");
```

Please see this http://jsfiddle.net/be26gv9c/2/ jsfiddle which almost does exactly what I need but I can't figure out where the extra underscores are coming from. I have very limited knowledge of javascript but am trying to learn.

Thanks for taking your time to read this, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing extras underscores because your HTML is malformed. Some of your `<em>` tags are missing closing `</em>` tags, so the DOM is inferring the placement of necessary but missing `</em>` tags.

In other words, innerHTML is not necessarily equal to whatever garbage HTML you actually typed.

Try console.logging the innerHTML to see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks for the quick concise answer.